# Variable sized message in MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing, mpi

Is there a library call that would allow for sending/receiving of variable sized messages using MPI?

A work around would be to send the data size in the first message and follow it with the actual payload, but I was wondering if there was a convention for combining these two separate messages.

Comment: In the general case, two messages with size and payload is the preferred method to pass a message where the size is not known until runtime.

Comment: That is the workaround, but it is not simple because the two messages can interfere with another pair in a different thread. Douglas Gregor and other discuss thread-safe approaches in this paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228737912_Dynamically-Sized_Messages_in_MPI-3 and make the case for a standard way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The count provided to MPI_Recv is only an upper bound. MPI_Get_count can be used to find the exact number of items received.

Kind of like sockets I guess.

Comment: The only caution is that the count and buffer size passed to MPI_Recv should agree in size.  If some reasonable bound on the message size can be made ahead of time, this can be an effective technique.  Otherwise, to accommodate the general case, there will be some number of buffers that are capable of holding a 32bit count of data types laying around.  This can seriously bloat memory footprint.

Comment: May you add an example? Would you use `MPI_Get_count()` and then something like `malloc(sizeof(char)*getCountResult)` and then pass the resulting buffer to `MPI_Recv()`?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `MPI_Probe` or `MPI_Iprobe` instead of posting a receive with `MPI_Recv` or `MPI_Irecv`.  Probe/Iprobe can have performance disadvantages if used incorrectly, but they are one common approach to dealing with variable-sized messages.  Also, be careful in a multithreaded environment because Probe/Iprobe are not safe in some multithreaded contexts.  See [Hoefler et al.](http://www.unixer.de/publications/img/hoefler-mprobe.pdf) for a thorough discussion of these problems and a sketch of the fix (Mprobe) likely to be included in MPI-3.