# Heap memory allocated but not free after calling MPI_TYPE_CREATE_STRUCT to create struct with allocatables

Tags: fortran, mpi

I'm trying to send/recv a derived datatype with allocatable arrays. Currently, I managed to follow the suggestion in [MPI derived datatype for dynamically allocated structs with dynamically allocated member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771975/mpi-derived-datatype-for-dynamically-allocated-structs-with-dynamically-allocate?noredirect=1#comment66838485_39771975). With that, my information is passed correctly. However, when I was profiling with tau, the memory allocated on heap wasn't freed and resulted in memory leak.

I have tested many times by commenting on/off different lines of code. The memory leak disappear as long as I comment off the MPI_TYPE_CREATE_STRUCT function.

I also pasted the code in the post into my code but problem still persists.

The compilers I tried are openmpi-4.0.0, 3.1.0 and impi 18.0.2, 18.0.0

Here is the a simple code I tested on

Here is the memory leak version

```
Program memory_leak

  implicit none
  include "mpif.h"
  TYPE Struct    
  INTEGER :: N
  DOUBLE PRECISION :: A
  DOUBLE PRECISION ,ALLOCATABLE :: B(:)
  END TYPE Struct
  TYPE(Struct) :: Structs(2)
  integer :: i
  integer :: Types(3)
  integer :: Blocks(3)
  integer :: Elem_Type(2), TwoElem_Type,IError
  integer(kind=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: POS_(3)
  integer(kind=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: Offsets(3)
  ALLOCATE(Structs(1)%B(10))
  ALLOCATE(Structs(2)%B(20))
  CALL MPI_INIT(IError)

  ! (1) Create a separate structure datatype for each record
  DO i=1,2
    CALL MPI_GET_ADDRESS(Structs(i)%N,    POS_(1), IError)
    CALL MPI_GET_ADDRESS(Structs(i)%A,    POS_(2), IError)
    CALL MPI_GET_ADDRESS(Structs(i)%B(1), POS_(3), IError)
    Offsets = POS_ - POS_(1)

    Types(1) = MPI_INTEGER
    Types(2) = MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION
    Types(3) = MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION

    Blocks(1) = 1
    Blocks(2) = 1
    Blocks(3) = i * 10

    CALL MPI_TYPE_CREATE_STRUCT(3, Blocks, Offsets, Types, Elem_Type(i), IError)
  END DO

  ! (2) Create a structure of structures that describes the whole array
  CALL MPI_GET_ADDRESS(Structs(1)%N, POS_(1), IError)
  CALL MPI_GET_ADDRESS(Structs(2)%N, POS_(2), IError)
  Offsets = POS_ - POS_(1)

  Types(1) = Elem_Type(1)
  Types(2) = Elem_Type(2)

  Blocks(1) = 1
  Blocks(2) = 1

  CALL MPI_TYPE_CREATE_STRUCT(2, Blocks, Offsets, Types, TwoElem_Type, IError)
  CALL MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(TwoElem_Type, IError)

  ! (2.1) Free the intermediate datatypes
  DO i=1,2
    CALL MPI_TYPE_FREE(Elem_Type(i), IError)
  END DO
  CALL MPI_TYPE_FREE(TwoElem_Type, IError)
  print *, "end"
  CALL MPI_FINALIZE(IError)

end program memory_leak
```

[Memory leak using tau](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMKGP.png)
\

Here is the Leak free version

```
Program memory_leak

  implicit none
  include "mpif.h"
  TYPE Struct    
  INTEGER :: N
  DOUBLE PRECISION :: A
  DOUBLE PRECISION ,ALLOCATABLE :: B(:)
  END TYPE Struct
  TYPE(Struct) :: Structs(2)
  integer :: i
  integer :: Types(3)
  integer :: Blocks(3)
  integer :: Elem_Type(2), TwoElem_Type,IError
  integer(kind=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: POS_(3)
  integer(kind=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: Offsets(3)
  ALLOCATE(Structs(1)%B(10))
  ALLOCATE(Structs(2)%B(20))
  CALL MPI_INIT(IError)

  ! (1) Create a separate structure datatype for each record
  DO i=1,2
    CALL MPI_GET_ADDRESS(Structs(i)%N,    POS_(1), IError)
    CALL MPI_GET_ADDRESS(Structs(i)%A,    POS_(2), IError)
    CALL MPI_GET_ADDRESS(Structs(i)%B(1), POS_(3), IError)
    Offsets = POS_ - POS_(1)

    Types(1) = MPI_INTEGER
    Types(2) = MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION
    Types(3) = MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION

    Blocks(1) = 1
    Blocks(2) = 1
    Blocks(3) = i * 10

   ! CALL MPI_TYPE_CREATE_STRUCT(3, Blocks, Offsets, Types, Elem_Type(i), IError)
  END DO

  ! (2) Create a structure of structures that describes the whole array
  CALL MPI_GET_ADDRESS(Structs(1)%N, POS_(1), IError)
  CALL MPI_GET_ADDRESS(Structs(2)%N, POS_(2), IError)
  Offsets = POS_ - POS_(1)

  Types(1) = Elem_Type(1)
  Types(2) = Elem_Type(2)

  Blocks(1) = 1
  Blocks(2) = 1

  ! CALL MPI_TYPE_CREATE_STRUCT(2, Blocks, Offsets, Types, TwoElem_Type, IError)
  ! CALL MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(TwoElem_Type, IError)

  ! ! (2.1) Free the intermediate datatypes
  ! DO i=1,2
  !   CALL MPI_TYPE_FREE(Elem_Type(i), IError)
  ! END DO
  !CALL MPI_TYPE_FREE(TwoElem_Type, IError)
  print *, "end"
  CALL MPI_FINALIZE(IError)

end program memory_leak
```

Comment: both programs are identical! you also forget to `DEALLOCATE(Structs(1)%B,Structs(2)%B)` in your app. If the problem persists, please state which MPI library (vendor and version) you are using.

Comment: Hi Gilles, I updated the second one. The difference is simply commenting create struct functions. The problem, I don't think is related to deallocation. Nonetheless, i tried adding in that line, but it doesn't work. I updated the version I used, but I'll state them here too, Openmpi 3.3 and 4.0, Intel mpi 18.0.2 and 18.0.0. All of them have memory leakage problems

Comment: there is no Open MPI 3.3 (3.0.3 ? 3.1.3?) nor 4.0 (4.0.0 ?). `valgrind` does not report any leak to me.

Comment: Its 3.1.0 and 4.0.0. Sorry for the confusion. I used valgrind on laptop also didn't find any leak. However, when I run it on HPC, and tau on HPC, leak was identified and memory usage was extremely and unreasonably high

Comment: Could this be a but in tau?

Comment: I highly doubt so. I have a few evidences: 1. my actual code consumes much more memory than expected, order of 10; 2. the memory consumption increases over time

Comment: Are you saying you observe the leak with an other program than the one you posted?

Comment: Here is a series of events with this memory leak detection:

1. Found that stackoverflow post and implement similar subroutines with different structs for my large program

2. Observed memory leak in both profiling tool tau and actual execution but not valgrind

3. Isolated the problem by commenting different lines. Leak is gone after commenting off that function 

4. Implement a small program as stated in the original post and still have memory leak detected by tau 

5. My conclusion is the leak is from that subroutine but not other part of code

Comment: i ran the core of your program in a loop and was unable to observe any leak via the `top` command. your comment suggest that the leak is gone in your real code after commenting datatype creation. At the very least, this suggests you are not using the derived datatype in your real code which is a bit puzzling. The odds that Open MPI and Intel MPI (that is MPICH based) both have a similar memory leak are pretty low, so unless you are able to show me a reproducer, I can only conclude the code you posted is not a good representation of your real code, and the leak is in the code you did not post.

Comment: How did you run using `top` command? I want to try that with my real code

Comment: Simply run `top` in an other terminal on the same system.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem lies in other part of code where I used the pack function on allocatable array. When you use pack, the array will result in memory lost since pointer is gone but the array is not deallocated