# Strategy to distribute fortran90 derived types which contains derived type in it

Tags: fortran, mpi

I want to distribute a derived type 'type_cell_list' which contains again a derived type 'type_cell' in it. The overall data types are like below.

```
module mod_data_structure

  implicit none

  type type_cell

    real(dp)         :: x (2), values(8)
    integer          :: flag_boundary, flag_dummy

  end type type_cell

  type type_cell_list                       ! < Global datatype which holds the global view

    integer          :: n_xcells            ! How many cells in x-direction in 'cell_list'
    integer          :: n_ycells            ! How many cells in y-direction in 'cell_list'
    type(type_cell)  :: cell (nxmax,nymax)  ! Please ignore 'nxmax' & 'nymax', these integers set upper limit of 'n_xcells' and 'n_ycells' which are decided as 'integer,parameter' at the compile time

  end type type_cell_list

  type type_cell_list_local                 ! < Local datatype which holds the local view of each process

    integer                      :: n_xcells           
    integer                      :: n_ycells            
    type(type_cell),allocatable  :: cell (:,:)

  end type type_cell_list_local

end module mod_data_structure
```

Reading [MPI derived datatype for dynamically allocated structs with dynamically allocated member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771975/mpi-derived-datatype-for-dynamically-allocated-structs-with-dynamically-allocate), it felt like that there might be `n_xcells*n_ycells` of different offsets, for which I have to construct MPI structs each. Since that is the last thing I want to do, I'm considering the strategy using `MPI_PACK` to distribute derived datatypes like below.

```
subroutine broadcast_cells(my_id, n_xlocal, n_ylocal, xlocal_start, ylocal_start, cell_list, cell_list_local)

  use mod_data_structure

  implicit none

  integer                   ,intent(in)   :: my_id, n_xlocal, n_ylocal, xlocal_start, ylocal_start
  type(type_cell_list)      ,intent(inout):: cell_list
  type(type_cell_list_local),intent(out)  :: cell_list_local

  type(type_cell)            :: acell

  integer                    :: i, ierr, my_id, position, bufsize, DLB_SIZE, INT_SIZE
  character,allocatable      :: buffer(:)

0)allocate ( cell_list_local%cell(n_xlocal, n_ylocal) ) 

  call MPI_PACK_SIZE (1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_COMM_WORLD, DBL_SIZE, ierr)
  call MPI_PACK_SIZE (1, MPI_INTEGER         , MPI_COMM_WORLD, INT_SIZE, ierr)

1)call MPI_BCAST(cell_list%n_xcells, 1, MPI_INTEGER, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
  call MPI_BCAST(cell_list%n_ycells, 1, MPI_INTEGER, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

  bufsize = cell_list%n_xcells * cell_list%n_ycells * ( (2+8)*DBL_SIZE + 2*INT_SIZE )

  allocate(buffer(bufsize))

  if ( my_id .eq. 0 ) then

    position = 0
2)  do j = 1,cell_list%n_ycells
      do i = 1,cell_list%n_cells

        acell = cell_list%cell(i,j)

        call MPI_PACK(acell%x,             2, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, buffer, bufsize, position, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
        call MPI_PACK(acell%values,        8, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, buffer, bufsize, position, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
        call MPI_PACK(acell%flag_boundary, 1, MPI_INTEGER         , buffer, bufsize, position, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
        call MPI_PACK(acell%flag_dummy   , 1, MPI_INTEGER         , buffer, bufsize, position, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

      enddo
    enddo

  endif

  call MPI_BCAST (buffer, bufsize, MPI_PACKED, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

  if (my_id .ne. 0) then

    position = 0
3)  do j = 1, cell_list%n_ycells
      do i = 1, cell_list%n_xcells

        call MPI_UNPACK(buffer, bufsize, position, acell%x,             2, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
        call MPI_UNPACK(buffer, bufsize, position, acell%values,        8, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
        call MPI_UNPACK(buffer, bufsize, position, acell%flag_boundary, 1, MPI_INTEGER         , MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
        call MPI_UNPACK(buffer, bufsize, position, acell%flag_dummy   , 1, MPI_INTEGER         , MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

        cell_list%cell(i,j) = acell

      enddo
    enddo

4)  cell_list_local%cell = cell_list%cell(xlocal_start+1 : xlocal_start+n_xlocal, ylocal_stasrt+1 : ylocal_start+n_ylocal )

  endif

  deallocate( buffer )

end subroutine broadcast_cells
```

In above psudo code, I marked 0)~4) at the left side of the code.

0) Allocating local derived datatype.

1) `MPI_BCAST` the least information that is needed to construct `do` loops for distribution.

2) `MPI_PACK` the whole global derived type.

3) `MPI_UNPACK` the whole global derived type, after which each processor 'know' the global situation.

4) Each processor takes its local portion from the `MPI_BCAST`ed global data.

For above situation, I have two questions,

1. The distributing routine above contains unnecessary `MPI_BCAST` of global data type in '3)', which might can be optimized by using `MPI_SEND` instead of `MPI_BCAST`. Will the difference in the performance between the optimized version and the current `MPI_BCAST` version huge?
2. I expect this kind of situation in which one has to distribute a derived type that contains again a derived type is pretty common. However, I couldn't find a good example how a experienced researcher would do in this kind of situation. How would you like to deal with this situation? Would you use `MPI_PACK` and `MPI_BCAST` as I did, or would you use method with `MPI_Type_Create_struct` and so on? Any comments or any useful keywords would really be appreciated.

   Thank you for reading this question.

Comment: What is the final goal? To broadcast it once and forget? Or to do it often?

Comment: @VladimirF Being part of my own CFD code, data should be broadcasted and collected once (or even more depending on numerical schemes utilized) in every time steps. Data should be keep 'collected' (not only being distributed) since they have to know their boundaries' information from their adjacent processes. This might be able to be optimized by only communicating so-called 'guard cells', but since they introduce more complication with all the mappings btwn processes, I'm considering of full collecting of data at the present moment.

Comment: you can simply achieve this with two `MPI_Bcast()`. First send the metadata (e.g. `%n_xcells` and `%n_ycells`, and then send the cells (e.g. `n_xcells*n_ycells` consecutive cells at `%cell`).

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Could you elaborate it more for me? By '```n_xcells*n_ycells``` consecutive cells at ```%cell```', do you mean that ```%cell```s are stored at contiguous memory site even though they are a derived data type?

Comment: `%cell` are indeed stored at contiguous memory, regardless they are a regular or derived data type.

Comment: cell_list%cell is contiguous and stored within the type. Each cell_list_local%cell is also contiguous but stored somewhere else.

Comment: @VladimirF You mean, for example, ```cell_list%cell(1,2)``` follows ```cell_list%cell(1,1)```  after '(2+8)*DBL_SIZE + (1+1)*INT_SIZE' sites? Or do you mean ```cell_list%cell(i,j)```s are at contiguous memory as a some kind of pointer pointing ```cell%x``` and ```cell%x``` and ```cell%values``` and so on exist at some relative offset to each other?

Comment: Fortran is column-major https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order  Fortran multidemnsional arrays (static and allocatable) are cpntiguous in memory.

Comment: @SANGJUNLEE I strongly encourage you to build a [MCVE] and double check this by yourself!